# How to delete multiple nodes using igraph

Tags: igraph

I would like to delete multiple nodes in a graph (visualization of network) already created. I have following code:

```
edges.to.color.1 <- list(c("A","D"),
                         c("G","C"))

netColoredEdges(focal.node="", 
    list.with.edges=edges.to.color.1, 
    net=base.net.node, color="red", 
    width=0, 
    file.name="graph_02.pdf", 
    list.with.nodes.to.delete = list(c("B", "C", "A")) )
```

But I get a problem:

```
Error en netColoredEdges(focal.node = "D", list.with.edges = edges.to.color.1,  : 
  unused argument (list.with.nodes.to.delete = list(c("B", "C", "A")))
```

Any help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: where does `netColoredEdges` function come from?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with igraph, so please consider removing that tag. Thanks.